# In Flutter I want to be able to display the text I wrote last time and add text to it

Tags: flutter

in flutter,I'm currently working on a feature to edit lists.
I want to be able to display the last text I wrote and add text to it.
But I get an error like the one below.
I don't know how to do this anymore, so I would appreciate any advice on how to write it.
I'm sorry, but I don't understand English, and there are a few places where it's written in Japanese. answers don't have to be in Japanese.
This is my first question.

```
enter code here
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  // 最初に表示するWidget
  runApp(Myenter code hereApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // 右上に表示される"debug"ラベルを消す
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      // アプリ名
      title: 'My Todo App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // テーマカラー
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      // リスト一覧画面を表示
      home: TodoListPage(),
    );
  }
}

// リスト一覧画面用Widget
class TodoListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodoListPageState createState() => _TodoListPageState();
}

class _TodoListPageState extends State<TodoListPage> {
  // Todoリストのデータ
  List<String> todoList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // AppBarを表示し、タイトルも設定
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('リスト一覧'),
      ),
      // データを元にListViewを作成
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: todoList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CupertinoContextMenu(
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(todoList[index]),
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              CupertinoContextMenuAction(
                child: const Text('Delete'),
                //押されたら...
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                  //listの一つを削除
                  todoList.removeAt(index);
                  //そして、popで前の画面に戻る
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              CupertinoContextMenuAction(
                child: const Text('To edit'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  var morenewText = await Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => TodoAddPage(todoList[index]),
                    ),
                  );
                  setState(() {
                    todoList[index] = morenewText;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          // "push"で新規画面に遷移
          // リスト追加画面から渡される値を受け取る
          var newListText = await Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              // 遷移先の画面としてリスト追加画面を指定
              return TodoAddPage(null);
            }),
          );
          if (newListText != null) {
            // キャンセルした場合は newListText が null となるので注意
            setState(() {
              // リスト追加
              todoList.add(newListText);
            });
          }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TodoAddPage extends StatefulWidget {
  dynamic oldnama;
  TodoAddPage(this.oldnama);

  @override
  _TodoAddPageState createState() => _TodoAddPageState();
}

class _TodoAddPageState extends State<TodoAddPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('リスト追加'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // 入力されたテキストを表示
            Text(widget.oldnama, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            // テキスト入力
            TextField(
              // 入力されたテキストの値を受け取る（valueが入力されたテキスト）
              onChanged: (String value) {
                // データが変更したことを知らせる（画面を更新する）
                setState(() {
                  // データを変更
                  widget.oldnama = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Container(
              // 横幅いっぱいに広げる
              width: double.infinity,
              // リスト追加ボタン
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // "pop"で前の画面に戻る
                  // "pop"の引数から前の画面にデータを渡す
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(widget.oldnama);
                },
                child: Text('Add list', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Container(
              // 横幅いっぱいに広げる
              width: double.infinity,
              // キャンセルボタン
              child: TextButton(
                // ボタンをクリックした時の処理
                onPressed: () {
                  // "pop"で前の画面に戻る
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('Cancel'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your error log to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant directly modify the widget entry variables

```
TextField(
              // 入力されたテキストの値を受け取る（valueが入力されたテキスト）
              onChanged: (String value) {
                // データが変更したことを知らせる（画面を更新する）
                setState(() {
                  // データを変更
                  widget.oldnama = value;
                });
              },
            ),
```

create another variable in state class like

```
var textValue = user.name;
```

use textFormField

```
TextFormField(
 initValue: textValue,
 onChanged: (value){
  setState( () {
   textValue = value;
  });
 },
)
```

or something like this, the important thing is that you cant do `widget.oldnama = value`

Comment: I don't know the user.name part, so could you tell me a little more about it?

Comment: @金武拓杜 it was an examle

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Reason: `null` value cause `Text` widget has excepiton, you can change from

```
Text(widget.oldnama, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
```

to

```
widget.oldnama == null
            ? Text("empty")
            : Text("${widget.oldnama}",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  // 最初に表示するWidget
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // 右上に表示される"debug"ラベルを消す
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      // アプリ名
      title: 'My Todo App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // テーマカラー
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      // リスト一覧画面を表示
      home: TodoListPage(),
    );
  }
}

// リスト一覧画面用Widget
class TodoListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodoListPageState createState() => _TodoListPageState();
}

class _TodoListPageState extends State<TodoListPage> {
  // Todoリストのデータ
  List<String> todoList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // AppBarを表示し、タイトルも設定
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('リスト一覧'),
      ),
      // データを元にListViewを作成
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: todoList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CupertinoContextMenu(
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(todoList[index]),
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              CupertinoContextMenuAction(
                child: const Text('Delete'),
                //押されたら...
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                  //listの一つを削除
                  todoList.removeAt(index);
                  //そして、popで前の画面に戻る
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              CupertinoContextMenuAction(
                child: const Text('To edit'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  var morenewText = await Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => TodoAddPage(todoList[index]),
                    ),
                  );
                  setState(() {
                    todoList[index] = morenewText;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          // "push"で新規画面に遷移
          // リスト追加画面から渡される値を受け取る
          var newListText = await Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              // 遷移先の画面としてリスト追加画面を指定
              return TodoAddPage(null);
            }),
          );
          if (newListText != null) {
            // キャンセルした場合は newListText が null となるので注意
            setState(() {
              // リスト追加
              todoList.add(newListText);
            });
          }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TodoAddPage extends StatefulWidget {
  dynamic oldnama;
  TodoAddPage(this.oldnama);

  @override
  _TodoAddPageState createState() => _TodoAddPageState();
}

class _TodoAddPageState extends State<TodoAddPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('リスト追加'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // 入力されたテキストを表示
            widget.oldnama == null
                ? Text("empty")
                : Text("${widget.oldnama}",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            // テキスト入力
            TextField(
              // 入力されたテキストの値を受け取る（valueが入力されたテキスト）
              onChanged: (String value) {
                // データが変更したことを知らせる（画面を更新する）
                setState(() {
                  // データを変更
                  widget.oldnama = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Container(
              // 横幅いっぱいに広げる
              width: double.infinity,
              // リスト追加ボタン
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // "pop"で前の画面に戻る
                  // "pop"の引数から前の画面にデータを渡す
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(widget.oldnama);
                },
                child: Text('Add list', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Container(
              // 横幅いっぱいに広げる
              width: double.infinity,
              // キャンセルボタン
              child: TextButton(
                // ボタンをクリックした時の処理
                onPressed: () {
                  // "pop"で前の画面に戻る
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('Cancel'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```